# Sequelize with postgres defaults to mysql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm setting up Sequelize to manage postgres in a Node.js app.

I've required sequelize-postgres, as well as declared 'postgres' in the dialect attr when instantiating a new Sequelize object. But for some reason, it defaults to using mysql.

Exact error message:

```
/Users/...project/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connector-manager.js:306
    var connection = mysql.createConnection(connectionConfig);
                           ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'createConnection' of undefined
    at module.exports.connect (.../node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connector-manager.js:306:28)
    at Object.pool.Pooling.Pool.create 

(.../node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connector-manager.js:131:19)
    at createResource (.../node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/generic-pool/lib/generic-pool.js:258:13)
    at dispense (.../node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/generic-pool/lib/generic-pool.js:250:9)
    at Object.me.acquire (.../node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/generic-pool/lib/generic-pool.js:316:5)
    at null.fct (.../node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connector-manager.js:241:19)
    at null.<anonymous> (.../node_modules/sequelize/lib/emitters/custom-event-emitter.js:24:18)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:336:15)
```

Any help is appreciated thank you!

Comment: try "pg" instead of "postgres"

Comment: as a value of the dialect attr? that didn't work for me. good suggestion though =]

Comment: can you post your app's config code? in particular config/connections.js, config/env/development.js, and config/env/production.js.

Comment: Thank you but figured it out! Silly mistake. all params are necessary when using postgres
sequelize = new Sequelize('dbname', 'username', 'pw', {
        dialect: 'postgres',
        sync: {force: true},
        syncOnAssociation: true,
        pool: { maxConnections: 5, maxIdleTime: 30}
    }),

Comment: Thanks, @NicoleZhu. Where did you find that info?